# Clearing output of a terminal program in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, unix, terminal

I want to clear the output of a C program produced with printf statements. I want to clear only one line, for example:

[source]

```
printf("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n");
printf("BBBBBBBBBBBBBB\n");
printf("CCCCCCCCCCCCCC\n");
printf("DDDDDDDDDDDDDD\n");
```

[terminal]

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

[I hope]

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

I will "DDDDDDDDDDDDDD" line in write other string.
I just want the above A, B, C sentences to left.
Only clear D sentences to change the other sentences,
unconditionally output D sentences.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There're several ways to delete the DDDDDDDDDDDDDD

1. **Print backspace several times**

```
printf("\b");
```

2. **Print carriage-return and then print something to override the original line**

```
printf("\r");
```

3. **If you are in a newline. You may use terminal commands to move your cursor**

such as `printf("\033[8;5Hhello");  // Move to (8, 5) and output hello`

Other commands:

```
printf("\033[XA"); // Move up X lines;
printf("\033[XB"); // Move down X lines;
printf("\033[XC"); // Move right X column;
printf("\033[XD"); // Move left X column;
printf("\033[2J"); // Clear screen
...
```

4. **Don't forget ncurses**

It is the best ways to control the exact layout and format in a terminal

Comment: `\033[8;5Habcd` what's means?

Comment: Move to (8,5) and output abcd. ;) In your case you should use `printf("\033[1A")` to move up one line.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using X-Term compatibles (Gnome Terminal included), then print the following

```
printf("\033[2J");
```

or

```
cout << "\033[2J";
```

where `\033` is the escape character in **ASCII** and `[2J` is the specific action (clear).

Answer (score 0):

I tried answering for what is best expected here.

```
printf("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
printf("BBBBBBBBBBBBBB");
printf("CCCCCCCCCCCCCC");
//printf("DDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
```

comment the last line or delete if you dont want to display in terminal. 
printf("xxxx") is the statement used for printing output in terminal.

Comment: You completely missed the point. The point is not to get it to stop printing, it's to clear it from the terminal (like if you want to refresh the terminal view, etc)