# How to clear a matrix in terminal, and print another matrix on the same position

Tags: c++, matrix, terminal

I print a matrix in the terminal. After the calculation, I got another matrix. I want to print the new matrix, to replace the old one. How to clear the old matrix in the terminal?
This code id for creating the matrix. When the calculation be done, this function will create a new matrix.

```
void TheNewMatrix(char newGame[20][50]){

    for(int row=0; row<20; row++){
        for(int col=0; col<50; col++){
            newGame[row][col]=nextStep[row][col];
            cout<<newGame[row][col];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Here is another code:

```
       for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            Sleep(1000);
            Roles(newGame);
            TheNewMatrix(newGame);
        }
```

Create some matrix, but I hope only show one matrix in the terminal. I tried '\r' and '\b', but they don't work.

Comment: There is no support in the standard library, so you need either platform specific code or a library such as ncurses to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nwp pointed, you'll need a platform specific code to clear the console screen. However, in module named `cstdlib` there's a function [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) which calls a specific command of system standard command processor. So, on Windows you can use

```
system("cls");
```

And on Linux,

```
system("clear");
```

Answer (score 1):

[ANSI control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) allow you to change terminal properties (newline and return are two examples of them), however those only work on a single line.
Take a note at the commands that allow you to clear the screen and move the cursor:

(from [Clearing output of a terminal program in Linux C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006262/clearing-output-of-a-terminal-program-in-linux-c))

```
printf("\033[XA"); // Move up X lines;
printf("\033[XB"); // Move down X lines;
printf("\033[XC"); // Move right X column;
printf("\033[XD"); // Move left X column;
printf("\033[2J"); // Clear screen
...
```

Do note that IO gets buffered, and many systems only 'flush' the to-be-outputted string after receiving a newline, so the control commands will only take effect when you manually flush the buffer: `fflush(stdout);`

Note: Support for these codes in windows is limited, have a look at the 'windows' section in the aforementioned wikipedia article for the details.